# Hapi handlebar template not displaying json object data

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, hapi.js

Hey guys I have this simple handler that reads a mysql table and returns the json obj to the route like so.

handler

```
var PostStore = {};

PostStore.getAllPosts = function(){
    conn.query('SELECT * FROM posts',function(err, result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
    });
}


module.exports = PostStore;
```

router

```
{
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        console.log(PostStore.getAllPosts);
        reply.view('index', { 
            title: 'My home page',
            posts: PostStore.getAllPosts
        });
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

{{#each posts}}
<h1>{{this.title}}</h1>
{{/each}}
```

Here is what the console output looks like

```
[Function]
[ { id: 1,
    title: 'Hello World',
    body: 'My First Post on this cool Hapi Blog!',
    date: null } ]
```

As you can see the sql result is parsed in to a JSON obj but not read from handlebars. Also note that the {{title}} is displaying "My home page" as expected.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`PostStore.getAllPosts` is async, you need to render the view inside it's callback function.

```
PostStore.getAllPosts(function (err, posts) {
// render the view 
});
```

Comment: how would I go about calling the PostStore.getAllPosts and passing "title" to the index view?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to render async method in view is to call this methods in a pre handler and assign the return value so you can render the returned data inside the view.  See here in hapi's documents for further explanation http://hapijs.com/api#route-prerequisites.

In PostStore routines this code

```
PostStore.getAllPosts = function(callback){
    conn.query('SELECT * FROM posts',function(err, result){
        if(err){
            return callback(err);
        }

        return callback(result);
});
```

}

Then in handlers code

```
const getPosts = function (request, reply) {

    ... // do something async to set posts
    PostStore.getAllPosts(function(err, results) {

        if (err) {
            return reply('Error occurred')
        }
        reply(results);
    };
};

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    config: {
        pre: [
            { method: getPosts, assign: 'posts' }
    ],
        handler: function (request, reply) {

            reply.view('index', { 
                title: 'My home page',
                posts: request.pre.posts,
            });
        }
    }
});
```